# Having problem on one tap sign in into my website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate google one tap sign in. I place the client id and login uri as documented, but I am getting this error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: .DumpException is not a function
```

Did you anyone have have faced this "DumpException" issue. If so can you please help me how you get rid of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code? Just by error, it's difficult to tell the solution.

Comment: ```<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>


<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="***"
     data-login_uri="***"
     style="position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 30px;
         width: 0; height: 0; z-index: 1001;">
</div> ```

Comment: Try using the method from this link http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: You need to add just 3 lines of code to your webpage for login.   First is ``<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>``. The second will be ``<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
`` in your header part of the page. The third line of code will be the Google Button ``<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>``

Comment: yes I tried that and it worked but the one tab button is older, I need it with "continue as button" like this one https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web

Comment: @NotABot When I used the script declaration that  you proposed, it stopped working in my local/development environment. Pretty sure that : https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client is the correct url, double-checked it here:https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/load-one-tap-client-library.  Not sure if the trusted community members are going to accept my edits to the the original problem, but it's working flawlessly in my local/development environment, but I get the same error on my staging website.

Comment: I've also tried removing the references to the localhost environment  in Authorized JavaScript origins, in case they were causing an issue.

Comment: @MikeT what exactly issues you are getting? Anything in ``console``?

Comment: @NotABot the same error the original poster was getting. I'm almost certain it's related to what I wrote in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Were you running One Tap example code inside a webview?

For security reasons, web view is prohibited. So, you may see some JS errors when downloading the JS client library.

Comment: @Guiibin I'm not, no, but getting the same error as the original poster. I've edited the original posters question, not sure if that was ok, or I should just create another Question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to Google requiring a Domain ownership verification:
[https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=[domain]&pli=1](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=%5Bdomain%5D&pli=1)

This is probably why very few people are experiencing this, as most have already verified their domain in the past for previous API credentials (Google Maps API, etc).